# Software which opens PSD files correctly on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am stuck in trying to find a software which can render PSD files properly under Ubuntu. I have tried GIMP and Krita but they both have problems with that - especially the clipping mask functionality.

Is there a working solution for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11):

If you are interested only in viewing them. This page: http://blog.pixarea.com/2011/10/opening-photoshop-psd-files-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot seems to suggest that LibreOffice will do the trick. If you need to edit them, you may have to resolve to Photoshop via Wine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try buying and installing Adobe Photoshop using a tool called PlayOnLinux: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/ CS6 seems to be Silver (applications with minor issues that do not affect typical usage) in Ubuntu 13.04 - http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607

Failing that you're just going to have to put up with GIMP (despite the problems) sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Should try KSquirrel. Its download page is:
 http://ksquirrel.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: GIMP is another best option to view psd in ubantu

Comment: +1 for GIMP. Getting selected layer position as simple as  [writing python script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31328/gimp-how-can-i-find-the-positions-of-a-layer) (**NO.**)

Comment: Gimp is a piece of **** legacy with a not friendly UI.